# How do I uninstall Ubuntu from a dual-boot with Windows 8?

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall

I'm definitely coming back to Ubuntu in the fall for one of my classes but for now I would like to uninstall it. The only problem is, I've heard that people who uninstall it improperly are unable to boot back into Windows 8 and I really can't have that.

Currently, my system has Ubuntu 13.04, Windows 7 and 8 [all 64-bit]. I originally installed Ubuntu by making a new partition on my disk drive and booting from my flash drive which had the Ubuntu 12.10 iso burned on to it. I then installed Ubuntu 12.10 on to that partition.

What's the safest way to uninstall Ubuntu with my setup?
Please and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20220216205931/https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/)?

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/

This requires you to have a working Windows installation disk.