# Uninstall Ubuntu from Lenovo IdeaPad Y510p

Tags: uninstall, lenovo

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad Y510p with Windows 8.1 Enterprise. I attempted to install Ubuntu 12.04 from a bootable USB and once the installation was complete and I rebooted, I was shown the black terminal screen and could not access the desktop. Startx does not work and every time I start the laptop, it boots straight to Linux. I can't access Windows at all. How do I remove Ubuntu and boot Windows again? The screen I see when I log on is this. https://www.dropbox.com/s/wpdfhk54va6ea9w/20140223_113205.jpg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I uninstall Ubuntu from a dual-boot with Windows 8?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288053/how-do-i-uninstall-ubuntu-from-a-dual-boot-with-windows-8)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a bootable CD/DVD or pendrive with Windows 8.1 on it.
2. Boot the CD/DVD/Pendrive and click on install and chose advance install option.
3. Delete the partition containing Ubuntu
4. Boot the CD/DVD/Pendrive again and click on repair your Computer.
5. Go to the command prompt and type this : bootrec.exe/fixmbr
6. Shutdown your Computer and remove the installation media and boot again.

I hope this will do.

Comment: I edited the post to show you what the startup screen looks like. How do I proceed from there?